# Form is not a control?

Tags: .net, forms, msdn

Well yesterday somebody noted that Form is not a control. Is that right? It inherits the properties like ClientSize which description clearly says it determines the area of control etc.
Or is it just MSDN being non accurate?

Comment: Who is "somebody?"  The answers all seem to indicate that MSDN *is* accurate and that `Form` is derived from `Control` - where have you heard otherwise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375088/what-is-the-base-class-form-windows-form

Comment: It would have been more useful if you'd left a comment on that answer, rather than asking a fairly vague question here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "is not a control"? If you looks at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) it clearly shows that it derives (indirectly) from System.Windows.Forms.Control...

Comment: Somebody says that Form is not a control but window or dialog box so I am consufed.

Comment: @Mocco: Well you should ask that person *exactly* what they mean. It's a control in some senses (in that you can do *most* things that you can do with a normal control with a form) but there are limitations - I don't think you can add one form to the controls of another form, for example.

Answer (score 5):

[Inheritance hierarchy according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx):

```
System.Object 
  System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.ComponentModel.Component
      System.Windows.Forms.Control
        System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl
          System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl
            System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

This includes `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, so it derives from `Control`. Or do you mean some other definition of "not a control"?

Answer (score 0):

The [inheritance hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) indicates otherwise.  (Unless they're not following the "is a" rule for inheritance, but I don't see that problem here.  They'd probably have been called out on that years ago if that were the case.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a matter of how you define 'control'.